# Efficient way to compare arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I've got 10 boolean arrays and I need to find a way to check if two or more are matching.

Example (with just 3 arrays to keep it simple):

```
array1[0]=false   array2[0]=true   array3[0]=false     => less than 2 are true
array1[1]=true    array2[1]=true   array3[1]=true      => 2 or more are true
```

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: Are you just looking to count how many "true"s are at each index location across multiple arrays?

Comment: If all of the arrays are the same size and you need to know if each index is matching, the best you can do is O(N). Have an outer loop then check each index where you short circuit once you find two values of `true`. The other option would be to keep track of the `true` values for each array. Store some data structure, most likely a `Dictionary` that stores a key as the index, and a value as a count. Whenever a new bool is set to true, increment that index. Whenever a bool is set to false, decrement that index. If you would like an example I can add one.

Comment: You should not use several Boolean arrays, but rather one numeric array.
Instead of assigning true and false, increment for true values. Then you immediately get your greater-than-or-equal-to-two counters.

Answer (score 2):

If you want count `true`s at each index of the arrays, I suggest organizining arrays into a *collection* (let it be `arrays`):

```
  bool[] array1 = new bool[] { false, true};
  bool[] array2 = new bool[] { true, true };
  bool[] array3 = new bool[] { false, true };

  ...

  // Add as many arrays as required
  var arrays = new bool[][] {
   array1,
   array2,
   array3,
 };
```

then you can *query* this `arrays` with a help of *Linq*:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 int[] trueCounts = Enumerable
   .Range(0, arrays.Max(array => array.Length))
   .Select(i => arrays.Count(array => i < array.Length && array[i]))
   .ToArray(); 

 // Let's have a look:
 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, trueCounts));
```

Outcome:

```
 1
 3
```

You can customize the output:

```
 string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, trueCounts
   .Select(c => $"{(c < 2 ? "less than 2 are true" : "2 or more are true")}"));

 Console.Write(result);
```

Outcome:

```
 less than 2 are true 
 2 or more are true
```